# Two UITableView Cell color alteration

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I Would like each two cells to have the same background color
so cell 1 and 2 is Color_FIRST
cell 3 and 4 is Color_Second
cell 5 and 6 is COLOR_first
and so on..
so at the end i am trying to flip the COLOR_CURRENT but code does not seem to work;

`.h file`

```
extern UIColor *   COLOR_FIRST;
extern UIColor *   COLOR_SECOND;
extern UIColor *   COLOR_CURRENT;
```

`.m file`

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIColor*  COLOR_FIRST = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:21.0f/255 green:180.0f/255  blue:1   alpha:1];
     UIColor*  COLOR_SECOND = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0/255.f green:255/255.f  blue:0 alpha:1];
     UIColor*  COLOR_CURRENT = COLOR_SECOND;
     cell.contentView.backgroundColor = COLOR_CURRENT;
     if ( indexPath.row % 2) {
//flip COLOR_CURRENT if in EVEN cell
         if (COLOR_CURRENT == COLOR_FIRST) {
             UIColor*  COLOR_CURRENT = COLOR_SECOND;
         }else{
             UIColor*  COLOR_CURRENT = COLOR_FIRST;
         }
     }
     return cell;
  }
```

Thank you all;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (indexPath.row % 4 == 0 || indexPath.row % 4 == 1) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = COLOR_FIRST;
} else {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = COLOR_SECOND;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your table view delegate as slim as possibile.

You can create a UITableViewCell extension.

***UITableViewCell+Color.h***

```
@interface UITableViewCell(Color)

-(void)setColorForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;

@end
```

***UITableViewCell+Color.m***

```
@implementation UITableViewCell(Color)

-(void)setColorForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row % 4 == 0 || indexPath.row % 4 == 1) {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = COLOR_FIRST;
    } else {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = COLOR_SECOND;
    }
}

@end
```

And then:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    /* DEQUEUE CELL HERE */

    [cell setColorForIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;

}
```